# UIActivityIndicator as UITableView footer shows different behavior in devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

AM using a `UIActivityIndicator` view as a `UITableViewFooter`, works fine in simulator, but shows different behavior in devices,think that occurs due to OS change.
Sometimes it fits to the width of the screen and seems enlarged, in other cases simply disappears, Any solution?

Comment: i just think about this type of problem,bcoz previous in my project i had this type of problem but my project working perfect in Simulator but not in Device .. in Device UIImageView are display frame differ from another view so now i confused whats wrong here..

Comment: may be this type of problem occure when status bar hidden for some views and hide in another.. so just check.. i just give idea about that.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason myself, adding UIActivityIndicator as footer causes trouble in certain devices, so its better to use text like "Loading..."if you still need to show a footer.Else add an extra cell to UITableView and add UIActivityIndicator to that last cell.
In my case, the error was while testing in 3GS, no trouble in other devices.

Regards